# Not able to reference value of variable in Robot Framework

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, robotframework, selenium3, acceptance-testing

In Robot Framework, I want to reference the value of a variable, I had set earlier. But when I reference the value by:

```
xpath= //*[text()=\${uid}]
```

I do not get the value of the variable uid but instead, I get an error

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: 
Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[text()=${uid}] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': 
The string '//*[text()=${uid}]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

It just takes the `uid` as the part of the XPath instead of referencing it. As you can see, I tried to escape the `$` sign by adding a backslash (`\`), but it doesn't do anything. It is not even shown in the expression shown in the error.

If anyone has any solution, kindly share them.

Comment: Please share your robot script as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the variable in double quotes?

```
//*[text()="${uid}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to call the XPath with dynamic value.

1.Create one python file name ConfigVariables.py

```
uid="test" 
my_Xapth='xpath=//*[text()=\''+uid+'\']'
```

Save this file.

2.Import this file in .robot file under the setting keyword.

```
 *** Settings ***
 Variables       ../Variables/ConfigVariables.py
```

Now try to call `my_Xapth` variable in the test case, I hope this should work.